# Stop MFMessageComposeViewController from sending?

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, user-feedback

I use an `MFMessageComposeViewController` in my app for users to submit feedback and fill out a survey. This is a rudimentary system where the email is prepopulated with a text that has a series of questions which they answer directly in the email, e.g.

```
Where did you hear about the app?
What are some suggestions for how to improve it?
How many times a week do you use the app?
```

I get great feedback from users with this mechanism. However, I often get emails from users who don't actually answer the questions -- they leave everything blank and just hit 'send'. This is quite annoying as it fills up my inbox and makes it harder to find actual support requests. Is there a way to stop `MFMessageComposeViewController` from sending a message when the user hits 'send', and show a popup, based on some logic (e.g. if the message is still the same as when it started, or something)?

Answer (score 0):

No,To solve your problem the right approach(according to me)is , made a screen with all your question listed their and ask user to answer them.At the bottom of page add a button that validates that's each question has been answered and populate your mail body message accordingly.In this you will tackle your situation.